# SVG image doesn't display at printing on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, images, printing

I'm using SVG image on Google Sheets like this.

`=IMAGE("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/AJ_Digital_Camera.svg")`

The SVG image display on Google Sheets, but it doesn't display at printing preview or actually printing.

How can I print SVG image which is used on Google Sheet?

To convert SVG to PNG, and use png is better?